# html form inside php tag radio button validation?

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, radio-button

how to validate the radio buttons. at least one options is selected.

the code will display a question and 3 answers as radio buttons from a database.
for example

```
what is Captial of India?
O New Delhi
O Chennai
O Mumbai
```

user has to select a correct answer. if the user not selecting any answer and click submit, I want to show a message "please answer the question".?

my code:

```
<?php

$today=date("Y-m-d");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
echo "<form method='post' id='submit' action='checkresult.php' dir='rtl'>";
$sql="SELECT * FROM cquestions where showdate='$today' limit 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<p>" . $row['cqtext'] . "</p>";
$sql2="SELECT * FROM canswers where cqid=".$row['cqid'];
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
echo "<input type='radio' name='".$row['cqid']."' value='".$row2['cqans']."' />".$row2['aatext'];
echo"<br>";
}
}
echo"<br>";
echo"<br>";
echo"<br>";
echo "<div align='left' style='padding-left:160px;'>";
echo"<input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='التالي' />";
echo "</div>";
echo "</form>" ;
?>
```

how to do it using javascript?

I tried like this.

```
echo "<form name='q1' method='post' id='submit' action='checkresult.php' onsubmit='return validateForm()';>";

echo "<input type='radio' id='a' name='".$row['cqid']."' value='".$row2['cqans']."' />".$row2['aatext'];
```

and this worked.

```
function validateForm() 
{
var a = document.getElementById('a');
if ( (a.checked == false ) )
{
alert ( "Please answer the question ");
return false;
}
}
```

**it worked.**

```
function RadioValidator()
{
    var ShowAlert = '';
    var AllFormElements = window.document.getElementById("submit").elements;
    for (i = 0; i < AllFormElements.length; i++) 
    {
        if (AllFormElements[i].type == 'radio') 
        {
            var ThisRadio = AllFormElements[i].name;
            var ThisChecked = 'No';
            var AllRadioOptions = document.getElementsByName(ThisRadio);
            for (x = 0; x < AllRadioOptions.length; x++)
            {
                 if (AllRadioOptions[x].checked && ThisChecked == 'No')
                 {
                     ThisChecked = 'Yes';
                     break;
                 } 
            }   
            var AlreadySearched = ShowAlert.indexOf(ThisRadio);
            if (ThisChecked == 'No' && AlreadySearched == -1)
            {
            ShowAlert = ShowAlert + ThisRadio + ' يرجى الإجابة على السؤال\n';
            }     
        }
    }
    if (ShowAlert != '')
    {
    alert(ShowAlert);
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: if the user clicks submit it will goes to next question.  he must answer the question. now without selecting any answer if we click submit it goes to next question. I want to prevent that.

Comment: Incoming data should always be validated. In this case it can only be done by php.

Comment: how to do it in php?

Comment: On w3schools you can find a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp "w3schools tutorial") for validating form data with php.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't worked because of your JS function declaration which is wrong.

This is the right way of declaring a function. Remember to use the curly brackets.

```
function validateForm() {
   var a = document.getElementById('a');
   if (!a.checked)
   {
     alert ( "please answer the question ");
     return false;
   }
}
```

Also, if you want us to know why the php code isn't working we need to look at the source code.

Comment: no. its not working.. the php code is working. just I want to make sure the user answered the question. if he click submit without answering the question should show a message please answer the question. the page should not go to checkresult.php.

Answer (score 0):

once try this..

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if($row['cqid']=="")
{
echo "Please select an answer";
}
}
```

I don't know whether it works or not.. but once give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<form name='q1' method='post' id='submit' action='checkresult.php' onclick='return validateForm(e)';>";

<script type="text/javascript">

function validateForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = document.getElementById('a');
  if ( (a.checked == false ) )
  {
    alert ( "please answer the question ");
    return false;
  }
}

</script>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

> if the user not selecting any answer and click submit, I want to show a message "please answer the question".? ... how to do it using javascript?

You will need to check that any one of the radio buttons is checked. A convenient way to do this is give them all a class, then retrieve all the DOM elements with that class name.

Here is an example.

```html
<form onsubmit="return validateForm();">
  <!-- note how all the radio buttons have the same name -->
  <input type='radio' class="question" name='question' value='New Delhi' />
  <input type='radio' class="question" name='question' value='Chennai' />
  <input type='radio' class="question" name='question' value='Mumbai' />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<script>
  function validateForm() {
    var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('question'),
      i = 0;

    for (; i < questions.length; i++) {
      if (questions[i].type === 'radio' && questions[i].checked) {
        alert('You selected ' + questions[i].value 
                              + ', the form will submit now');
        return true;
      }
    }
    alert('please answer the question');
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

However if you have multiple forms on the page you should take care that the radio button belongs to the form that is being submitted.